# IF in Selenium Webdriver

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have to select a value from drop down button and drop down button contain two value Yes and No
If I select Yes one more question will be trigger on the screen and if I select No, no question will be triggered.
Is the below code correct? Or lets us the easiest way to write this.

```
if (driver.findElement(By.id(""))== selectByVisibleText("Yes"));            
{
    String fpal = s.getCell(26, row).getContents();
    driver.findElement(By.id("")).sendKeys(fpal);
}

if (driver.findElement(By.id(""))== selectByVisibleText("No"));
{
    String fpal = s.getCell(26, row).getContents();
    driver.findElement(By.id("")).sendKeys(fpal);
}
```

Comment: The code is hard to understand. What is `s`?

Answer (score 1):

This is a basic programming question rather than Selenium, I would suggest you check out a beginners tutorial or two before posting more questions.

Some points though:

1. You'll need to use an actual element ID in `driver.findElement(By.id(""))`
2. There should be no `;` at the end of the `if` statement
3. You'll probably want to use the selenium method getAttribute to find the selected value of the dropdown box (once you fix point 1)

eg. `if (driver.findElement(By.id("element123")).getAttribute("value").equals("Yes"))`